# Timestamp in a json file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unix-timestamp

I am testing this RESTFul whois API .

I am confused if the date is in unix timestamp format . 
But I don't think so, because  :

```
print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(int("1340578800000")))
```

gave me :

```
 ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

the date can be found here

```
updated: 1340578800000
```

in this file :

```
http://www.restfulwhois.com/example
```

I can't find any email or support in the website, that's why I am asking here . 
What do you think ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you have is the number of milliseconds since the epoch and [`time.localtime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime) expects the number of seconds.

> [from `gmtime()`]: Convert a time expressed in seconds since the epoch to ...

Note that while the string you recover is no different between these two, the more generally applicable solution is *probably* to do floating-point division in order to preserve the milliseconds.

```
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(int("1340578800000") / 1000))
'2012-06-24 18:00:00'
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(int("1340578800000") / 1000.))
'2012-06-24 18:00:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are milliseconds since epoch:

```
>>> print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(int("1340578800000")/1000))
2012-06-25 03:00:00
```

Most ofted you will get milliseconds from `JavaScript`, returned by [`getTime`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp).

And beware of timezone and local time variances, as show by simoultaneous yet different answers in this topic. For a UTC date use `gmtime` instead of `localtime`:

```
>>> print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(int("1340578800000")/1000))
2012-06-24 23:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Python [`time.localtime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime) expects the timestamp to be in seconds, you are passing it in milliseconds, so you will have to divide by 1000 in order to get it in seconds.

Change your code to:

```
>>> print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(int("1340578800000")/1000))
 '2012-06-24 20:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in miliseconds, not seconds. Just divide it by 1000 before formatting:

```
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(int("1340578800000") / 1000))
'2012-06-24 20:00:00'
```